# Encryption search time

Tags: algorithm, encryption

Assuming the internet can test 1 trillion DES keys per second continuously, what is the expected time to search the entire 56 bit key space of DES in hours?

If a distributed approach can check 1 trillion 128-bit IDEA keys/sec continuously, what is the expected time in years to search the entire 128-bit key space?

Again, if the distributed approach can check one trillion 256-bit AES keys/second continuously, how long would it take to search the entire 256-bit key space in years?

Comment: You can do this math yourself.

Comment: I would but I don't know what math to do. Is this a case of just 2^56 for the first is the number of hours?

Answer (score 2):

56 bit key space is 2^56 different keys

If we can test 1 trillion per second, we get 2^56/10^12 **seconds**. But the expected value (average) is half of that - because on average you'll only have to search half of the keys to find the one that works.

Converting to hours you get roughly 10 hours.

Same math with questions 2,3.

Comment: The question was edited to remove the part I'm referring to - @rgs now wants the answer for the 3rd question without having to do any thinking

Comment: I see.. I rolled it back -- at least it has some value then.